# Text File Formatting how to add white space in each row using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, system.io.file

How can I add white space in each rows to the exported file. I want to achieve is in each row is it has a total 44 character length. The content + white space to complete the 44 characters in every rows. I have a working code but I don't know how to apply the adding of white space see the last image in the question to give you an idea of what i'm trying to achieve thanks in advance.

**CODE**
[image: Code]

**RESULT**

[image]

**RESULT I WANT TO ACHIEVE**

[image]

In the goal image i have shown the result with white space in every row total of 44 character including white space. How to do that? Thanks in advance

Comment: In the future, it's probably a better practice to write and format your code, not post a picture of it.

Comment: As Mahendran says you should always post code as text, not as images. See the [formatting help](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 0):

You should give writing the code a crack, but here is a basic outline of what you need to be doing:

- count the characters in your string
- subtract them from 44
- add whitespace equivalent to the result of the previous

Example code:

```
Dim wsNeeded As Integer = 44 - dgvBilled.Rows(irow).Cells(col).Value.ToString().Length
Dim wsString As String = dgvBilled.Rows(irow).Cells(col).Value.ToString()
wsString.PadRight(wsNeeded,"&nbsp;") ' Maybe just "" instead of "&nbsp;"
Writer.Write(wsString)
```